# Start pending intent instead of main activity, on app icon click

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have a foreground service on my application. When service running, notification will be display with a pending intent(this pending intent is not my main activity). When click on the notification, pending intent will be starts. Its working fine.

Following are my activities

- Main activity - **LoginActivity.java**
- Pending intent activity(which displays when click on notification) - **HomeActivity.Java**

When click on app icon while service is running, I need to launch pending intent activity(**HomeActivity.java**) instead of main activity(**LoginActivity.java**)

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change what the launcher icon points to dynamically at runtime in a reliable fashion.

You are welcome to have it point to an activity set up with `Theme.NoDisplay`, which then determines what actual activity should display, starts that activity using `startActivity()`, and then calls `finish()` to get rid of itself.

Or, have the launcher icon always point to `HomeActivity`, which has the logic to detect that a login is needed and then starts `LoginActivity`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I'll go for second option(pointing HomeActivity as the main activity)